ag grid react how to close column custom component
I am using "ag-grid-react": "27.1.0" version , I want to display custom column component that displays some set of options and when user selects any option it should close and API will call. As this is not re-render every time so not able to use state to show and hide.
Is there any way to do this?
Here is the https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/header-template-forked-dl792l?file=%2Fsrc%2FcustomFilter.tsx
is there any other way to implement this case or I am missing something

You can close custom component by running
props.api.hidePopupMenu();

in handleOptionClick function of your CustomFilter component.
